# How session work in php if cookies and session id visibility in URL is disable

Tags: php, session-cookies, php-5.5

I read some article and after that  I understand that session will work in php if cookies are not enable on client system. So if cookies are not enable on client system then server will create a unique session id for the user and server will reconize the client by using this unique id. Now if cookies are not enabled the session id will be shown in the url and if there is any form on the page then input type hidden will be cretad with name of PHPSESSID. But if i will make the changes in php.ini then session id will not visible in url .Now suppose  I open a  page on my website  which doesn't have any form and because if have made the changes in php.ini so phpsessid will be not visible in url then how I will get the session data on that page. Please explain I have seen the other answer on stackoverflow and no one has consider this situation

Comment: Can you rephrase in a more coherent way? What's the actual question?

Comment: I want that if cookies is disable and session id visibility in url is also disable  then how we will get session on the page

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the following two links:

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572134/php-sessions-with-disabled-cookies-does-it-work)
- [Session Introductions - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

It is still possible, but it is not recommended. As soon as the user closes the browser, their session is lost, and they have to log in again.

Comment: Their session will be lost anyway as session cookies are flushed when the browser is closed. Only standard (non-session) cookies live longer.

Comment: I already go through the above link but I didn't understand that how I will get session on a page when cookies and getting data from url both are disable

Comment: @BorisShchegolev But how it will work when user has  not closed their browser

Comment: Why can't you get data from the url? Is it a host problem?

Comment: @Ricky prob privacy or security concerns about showing sessions in the URL

Comment: @Ricky No I just want to understand that if cookies and getting session id from url both are disable the how session will reach on that page

Comment: Why would you want to understand that?

Comment: @Ricky I want to understand that how session will reach on some page if session id is not coming from url and cookies has already disabled on user computer

Comment: You could probably then use POST statements but that would require you to embed the variables into every link they go to via the website.

Comment: @Ricky You mean if both are disable then session will not reach on website page

Comment: I don't see any scenario where this would be a problem.

Comment: @Ricky I am not saying that this will create any problem if someone will ask you this question then what will be your answer about this

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's say you have a client that does not accept cookies, at all. And your webserver has URL SESSIONID forwarding disabled. You are asking what will happen?

Absolutely nothing will happen. The server will issue a cookie, client will deny it. User will not be logged in, even if he provided the correct password. I mean he will log in successfully, but at the next request he will be asked to log in again.

If you want to avoid such a situation you can design your authentication differently. For example you can use OAUTH or any other token-based authentication. Then the server will send the token(s) without using the Cookie header, client-side JavaScript will store it (i.e. in the Web Storage) and send it back to the server with every request. This approach works well with AJAX-based applications.